# Split key value string in python and move it in a df column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

Here's the column that I have, I want to split into key - value and store in a new column in pandas df.

```
{"FontStyle"=>"Gill Sans Standard", "FontSize"=>"Medium (3mm)"}
{"Font Style"=>"Gill Sans Standard","Font Size"=>"Medium (3mm)"}
{"Font Style":"Script","Font Size":"Medium (3mm)"}
{"Font Style"=>"Gill Sans Standard","Font Size"=>"Medium (3mm)"}
{"Font Style":"Gill Sans Standard","Font Size":"Medium (3mm)"}
```

The main issue is that some of them have '=>' while some have colon

I want two new columns in df one for Font Style and another for Font Size and the respected values in them

if anyone can help me achieve this then it would be great, and also if you could recommend me some book/tutorial for regex that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: What is your required output, can you mention it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `regex` here is not necessary, use:

```
import ast

print (df)
                                                 col
0  {"FontStyle"=>"Gill Sans Standard", "FontSize"...
1  {"Font Style"=>"Gill Sans Standard","Font Size...
2  {"Font Style":"Script","Font Size":"Medium (3m...
3  {"Font Style"=>"Gill Sans Standard","Font Size...
4  {"Font Style":"Gill Sans Standard","Font Size"...
5                                                NaN
```

---

```
d = {'=>':':', 'FontSize':'Font Size','FontStyle':'Font Style'}

regex = '|'.join(r"{}".format(x) for x in d.keys())
df1 = (df['col'].dropna()
                .str.replace(regex, lambda x: d[x.group()], regex=True)
                .apply(ast.literal_eval))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist())[['Font Size','Font Style']].dropna(how='all')
print (df2)
      Font Size          Font Style
0  Medium (3mm)  Gill Sans Standard
1  Medium (3mm)  Gill Sans Standard
2  Medium (3mm)              Script
3  Medium (3mm)  Gill Sans Standard
4  Medium (3mm)  Gill Sans Standard
```

**Explanation**:

1. First remove missing rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)
2. Then use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for values in dictionary
3. Convert values to dictionaries by `ast.literal_eval`
4. Create new DataFrame
5. If necessary filter only columns by list and rmove only `NaN`s rows

Comment: I get this error message  `  malformed node or string: nan `

Comment: there are 145 null values in that column

Comment: the solution works fine, is there any way to merge those columns into just 2? and yes we need to remove the nan values

Comment: @Vijayaraghavan - Just see there is necessary multiple replace, so answer was edited.

Answer (score 2):

This is by far not the most efficient code but this would do the work.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

text = '''{"FontStyle"=>"Gill Sans Standard", "FontSize"=>"Medium (3mm)"}
{"Font Style"=>"Gill Sans Standard","Font Size"=>"Medium (3mm)"}
{"Font Style"=>"Script","Font Size"=>"Medium (3mm)"}
{"Font Style"=>"Gill Sans Standard","Font Size"=>"Medium (3mm)"}'''

my_list = []

text = text.replace("FontStyle", "Font Style")
text = text.replace("FontSize", "Font Size")
text = text.replace("=>", ":")
text = text.split("\n")

for one_dict in text:
    my_list.append(ast.literal_eval(one_dict))

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
print(df)
```

The output for the above code:

```
      Font Size          Font Style
0  Medium (3mm)  Gill Sans Standard
1  Medium (3mm)  Gill Sans Standard
2  Medium (3mm)              Script
3  Medium (3mm)  Gill Sans Standard
```

I hope this helps. :-) Let me know if it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import ast
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('=>', ': ').str.replace('FontSize', 'Font Size').str.replace('FontStyle', 'Font Style')
df['col']= df["col"].apply(lambda x : dict(ast.literal_eval(x)))
df1 = df['col'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why not to use eval?